# Angular always returning undefined or null in authentication system with firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm building an authentication system with `email and password` in `firebase` the login and logout both work fine as response `console.log(authState)` but the **`angular guard`** always returns the method `isLoggedIn()` is `null` I don't know why is that?! In the constructor I have defined it with userDetails value:

Code for just the auth.service constructor:

```
  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  public userDetails: firebase.User = null;


  constructor(
    private af: AngularFireAuth,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private statusMessage: ToastMessagesService
  ) {


    this.user = af.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      user => {
        this.userDetails = user;
        console.log(this.userDetails); // I get a response from this on the login page with user details ( user is logged in )
      }
    )

  }
```

Code of the method alone:

```
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return (this.userDetails != null) ? true : false;
  }
```

The code of the whole service ( auth.service.ts ):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/observable';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ToastMessagesService } from './toast-messages.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  public userDetails: firebase.User = null;


  constructor(
    private af: AngularFireAuth,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private statusMessage: ToastMessagesService
  ) {


    this.user = af.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      user => {
        this.userDetails = user;
        console.log(this.userDetails); 
      }
    )

  }

  async siginInRegular(username: string, password: string) {
    // const credentials = this.af.auth.email
    const results = await this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
      results => {
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
        this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${results.user.email}`);
      }
    );

  }

  async register(username: string, password: string) {
    try {
      return await this.af.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
        user => {
          this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/profile');
          this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${user.user.email}`);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  signOut() {
    return this.af.auth.signOut();
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return (this.userDetails != null) ? true : false;
  }



}
```

The code for the guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    console.log(auth.isLoggedIn());

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {


    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true
    }

    console.log('Access denied!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any reason to set to `null` at this line  `public userDetails: firebase.User = null;` use empty object instead.

Comment: `isLoggedIn` method returning null is impossible.

Comment: You should check this post https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/check-if-current-user-exists-with-angularfire/

Comment: @ritaj The isLoggedIn() always return false because the userDetails always is null witch weird to me as well

Comment: @ganesh045 it doesn't matter will return an empty object if I do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a race in your code. `this.userDetails` in your AuthService is not "ready" yet when you call it from your guard.

What you can do is, return a promise/observable in the `canActivate` method, as it accepts `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`.

a basic example could be this:

1. Add a method to get the auth state in your auth service:

   ```
    get authState(): Observable<any> {
      return this.af.authState;
    }
   ```
2. Use it in your `canActivate()` method:

   ```
   canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.authService.authState()
       .pipe(
            map(authState => !!authState),
            tap(auth => !auth ? console.log('Access Denied!') : true),
            take(1)
        );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! your approach works really well :)!  But I didn't understand still what cause this issue! because for example if I `console.log(this.userDetails)` in the `constructor` after the 'subscribe' if you look at the code above still gives me it's null!! but I'm sure it has a value because inside the subscribe when I `log` return a `value` but outside no!

Comment: I don't understand what are you referring to, try to be more clear so I can answer.

Comment: Sorry about that! for simplicity, the `userDetails` property always returns null whatever where I 'console.log()' it! the only place it returns a value when it's inside the `subscribe` my question is why is this happen?

Comment: `af.authState` is an asynchronous method - the `userDetails` property will be `null` until the `af.authState` observable will be resolved from the server.

Comment: Thanks for more explaining I have checked your answer :) have a nice day.